# SQL LEFT() not working as expected when used with GROUP BY and Partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have codes that are like 1231231A, 1231231A, 3453454B etc

I need to group them by their number (ignoring the char which is a version) and just get one of each. I also need to drop the last char. My code works in grouping them and returning one of each, but it returns the last char.

Why is it returning the last char when i chop it off?

Expected output is 
1231231
3453454
What I'm getting is 
1231231A
3453454B

```
        SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T.fldProductDescrip 
                             ORDER BY T.fldEffectiveDate DESC) AS rn
    FROM (
        -- Insert statements for procedure here
        SELECT JST.flduid
            ,JST.fldEffectiveDate
            ,(CASE 
        WHEN RIGHT(fldProductDescrip, 1) LIKE '[0-9]'
            THEN fldProductDescrip
        ELSE LEFT(fldProductDescrip, DATALENGTH(fldProductDescrip) - 1)
        END) as fldProductDescrip
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN PE.fldLogoutDateTime IS NULL
                        THEN PE.fldESigUser
                    ELSE ''
                    END
                ) AS LoggedIn
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN PE.fldLogoutDateTime IS NULL
                        THEN PE.fldLoginDateTime
                    ELSE ''
                    END
                ) AS LoggedInDateTime

        FROM tblJSJobSheetTemplates JST
        INNER JOIN tblJSProducts JP ON JST.fldProductUID = JP.fldUID
        INNER JOIN tblJSProductEsig PE ON JP.fldProductDescrip = PE.fldProduct
        ) AS T
    WHERE LoggedIn <> ''
    )AS G WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Most likely you should use `LEN` instead of `DATALENGTH`. What is the type of `fldProductDescrip`?

Comment: Hi Vlad, it's a varchar. I just tried LEN and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: If the type of `fldProductDescrip` is `varchar` (not `nvarchar`) and `LEN` instead of `DATALENGTH` works , then it most likely means that `fldProductDescrip` has trailing spaces.

Comment: I think you're right as the codes are user input and seems there's no removal of trailing spaces. Thanks a bunch vlad.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov This is why you don't answer in comments.